# Can I avoid using global variables in python while coding a bot with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord

I'm working on my first programming project, a discord bot, using discord.py. I wanted to add a minigame with a dice, but for that I used global variables. I understood that it's recommended not to use them and I was wondering, is there a way I can do the same thing without using global variables?

This is my code:

```
dice_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
roll_1 = ''
roll_2 = ''
player_1 = ''
player_2 = ''
@client.command()
async def dice(ctx):
    global roll_1
    global roll_2
    global player_1
    global player_2
    if roll_1 == '':
        roll_1 = random.choice(dice_list)
        player_1 = ctx.message.author
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention} rolled **{roll_1}**!')
    else:
        if ctx.message.author != player_1:
            roll_2 = random.choice(dice_list)
            player_2 = ctx.message.author
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention} rolled **{roll_2}**!')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'You already rolled {roll_1}, wait for someone to play with you.')
        if roll_1 > roll_2 and player_2 != '':
            await ctx.send(f'{player_1} won!')
            roll_1 = ''
            roll_2 = ''
            player_1 =''
            player_2 =''
        elif roll_2 > roll_1 and player_2 != '':
            await ctx.send(f'{player_2} won!')
            roll_1 = ''
            roll_2 = ''
            player_1 =''
            player_2 =''
        elif player_2 != '':
            await ctx.send('Tie!')
            roll_1 = ''
            roll_2 = ''
            player_1 =''
            player_2 =''
```

Comment: you should be able to just remove the variables declared in `dice()` as then the code will default to use the variables declared at the top of the code

Comment: Yes but I was wondering if there's a way I can do it by declaring variables inside the @client.command and not outside? So that I could use again "player_1" and "player_2" in other minigames for example.

Comment: You might consider moving this post over to the CodeReview Stack Exchange site, I think this code would benefit from a more detailed review than what you typically get on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndreiJula you just remove the `global` keyword in that case: also remove the variables at the top of the code

Comment: @reece I already tried that, but if I do it I get this: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'roll_1' referenced before assignment. And to solve it, I can keep the " =' ' " after every variable, but that breaks the functionability of my code, because it will not keep track of roll_1 and player_1. Every time someone does .dice the second time, the variables would reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set attributes of your bot.

```
client.roll_1 = "..."
```

These are available everywhere you have your client object.

If you want to use the variable elsewhere, of course it would be best if you declare a standard value at the beginning of you code, but you can also check if the attribute exists

```
if hasattr(client, "roll_1"):
    # work with client.roll_1
else:
    # roll_1 wasn't defined yet
```

I hope I could help